# Python Regex successfully tested on 3 online testers but not working in code

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to extract the IP's from the beginning and numbers at the end of the following multi-line string. I've tested it successfully on pythex.org, pyregex.com and regex101.com, but it doesn't work when the script is executed. Output of the regex statements are below.

Multi-line string (extracted from a Cisco router using paramiko to SSH):

```
sh ip bgp summ | in 192.168.190.
192.168.190.3   4          100     166     169       17    0    0 02:27:11            3
192.168.190.4   4          100     169     171       17    0    0 02:26:33            4
R1#
```

my regex is as follows (I've also tried using the regex flags in the conventional way, i.e as re.M):

```
re3=re.findall(r"(?im)^(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s+\b4\b.+\s+(\b\d{1,4}\b)$", string1)
```

when I run the following code:

```
print(type(string1))
print(type(re3))
print(len(re3))
print(re3)
```

Output is as follows:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
0
[]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you show output of `print(repr(string1))` ?

Comment: 'sh ip bgp summ | in 192.168.190.\r\n192.168.190.3   4          100     193     
    196       17    0    0 02:51:20        3\r\n192.168.190.4   4          100     
    195     197       17    0    0 02:50:42        4\r\nR1#'

Comment: Some online websites like https://texttoolkit.com/re.findall may help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string contains carriage return (`\r`, CR).

```
# without CR
>>> re.search('(?m)a$', 'a\n')  # matches
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>

# with CR
>>> re.search('(?m)a$', 'a\r\n')  # does not match
>>> re.search('(?m)a\r$', 'a\r\n')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='a\r'>
```

Adjust the regular expression to match the CR; Add `\r?` just before `$` (used `\r?` to make the CR optional)

---

```
re3 = re.findall(r"(?im)^(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s+\b4\b.+\s+(\b\d{1,4}\b)\r?$", string1)
#                                                                                          ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I feel silly that I missed that. I'll keep that repr(string) in mind!